# Getting PKIX path build failure for aws com.amazonaws.SdkClientException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

While I am trying to upload an object to the S3 bucket from java using Eclipse. I am getting below exception

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Please refer the link from which I have taken and execute the sample code

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html

Any help on this will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.
I seen on other posts (examples include
[forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290003](http://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290003)
and [github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1757](http://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1757)), that adding JDKs CACERTS to the eclipse.ini file has worked.
I have a Public S3 bucket and an IAM user with Admin rights, to ensure permissions were not causing this.

This is still an ongoing issue for me, but one of these may fix your issue uddeshya pratik

Comment: MarieORourke You should edit your _answer_ and move the contents with the links from your _comment_ there. Also it's recommended to include relevant information from the links into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Eclipse with AWS Java SDK 2 to execute the AWS Java SDK sample codes from AWS SDK documentation.
Here are the things I found. Newer Java versions have Amazon Root CA already in JDK truststore.

After troubleshooting the Application with with Parameter **-Djavax.net.debug=all**, or **-Djavax.net.debug=ssl** by passing vmargs in Run configurations,  it was throwing an exception from the Intermediate Root CA from ZScalar certificate. JDK truststore does not have that Intermediate Root CA.

Then I went to ZScaler website to download their root, and intermediate CA from  the URL. Here are the certificates that I downloaded. Add them to JDK truststore using the following command.

I have added root as well intermediate CA certificates from ZScaler, and then  Eclipse Java Application with AWS Java SDK worked well without giving any errors.

Summary is: Sometimes the problem is with Intermediate Root CAs that are not added to JDK trust store by default.

keytool -import -alias zscaler-int-ca1 -file zscaler-ca1.cer   -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/jre/security/cacerts

keytool -import -alias zscaler-root-ca1 -file zscaler-ca2.cer   -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/jre/security/cacerts

[Zscaler website URL to get CA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gQoh.png)